# What's the simplest way to password protect a text file?

Tags: macos, password, uti

I'd like to password protect a text file. Not necessarily a `.txt` file - just a file that's got text in it that I can edit with a standard text editor. I'd like to set a password and be prompted for it every time I open the file in any app. What's the best way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can put the file into an encrypted disk image.

1. Open "/Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility"
2. File > New > New Blank Image...
3. In the new image dialog make sure to choose:

   - Encryption = 128 or 256-bit AES
   - Image Format = read/write disk image
4. Because you chose encryption, you will be prompted to set a password for the disk image

You now have a password-protected disk image that you can save any kind of file in.

Comment: like this solution, "sparse disk image" is more appropriate if you want to start with a large disk size with some small files.

Comment: Is this the simplest way??

Answer (score 5):

#### Easy Method

**Appstore / GUI:**
Install the free software "[Encrypto](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/encrypto-secure-your-files/id935235287?mt=12)" from the Appstore. Encrypto: secure your files. Drop the file (e.g.: filename) you want to encrypt from Finder, add your password hint and then "save as", which gives you a filename.crypto. Don't forget to remove/delete the original file.

#### Advanced Method

**Terminal / Command Line:** find your text file and use gpg:

```
gpg --symmetric filename
```

which asks you for a password you have to give twice, the output is `filename.gpg` in the same directory.

Comment: Nice Answer! +1  I did some editing to make it stand out and help readers get a clear picture.

Answer (score 3):

You can print->save as PDF->password protect the PDF. It's not as transparent as having the .txt in a `DMG`, but it's easy enough to copy/paste the contents when it's time to edit.

Another container version akin to a `DMG` is `OpenPGP`. The suite for OS X is pretty nice, and it adds encrypt/decrypt to the services menu. It's very easy to right click your text file, choose 'Encrypt File' enter a password, verify, done.

Don't forget `Keychain Access` as well. It has the ability to create `Secure Notes`, which are password protected by the keychain they are stored in.

Comment: These seem like great options. Will test them out!

Comment: This doesn't solve the original question (the resulting text file isn't editable in a standard text editor), but it did solve my question of how to save a read-only text file with password protection, as the "Export to PDF" feature in TextEdit doesn't offer any security options.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're the file's owner, a built-in and system-wide way to do this would be to [adjust the file's permissions](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.7/en/mchlp1203.html) so that only a specific user or users (I'm assuming you want to lock the file so only *you* can view/edit it) can read or write to the file.

As Mark pointed out in the comments, however, this only protects you if:

- No other user has admin rights to the machine, and
- No one gains access to the machine while you're logged in

Making Coconut Man's solution by far a better one. I'll leave this answer here as an alternative that may be helpful in similar situations.

Comment: Even then anyone with admin rights or physical access to the machine can read the file (+ you need to be aware of how backups store the data)

Comment: Good point! I'll edit my answer to describe it as an alternative with said limitations.

Answer (score -1):

To add to @mirinade's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/453614/24527) you can setup the password using:

```
gpg --symmetric filename
```

You will need `gpg` installed for that, which you can easily do with `brew install gpg`

Then to decrypt it back to plaintext:

```
gpg -d filename
```

This will prompt you for the password